# Access Certain Key Value in PHP Array

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and got confused, I wrote a PHP script to log the server environment variables when user make request, and my code looks like this:

```
<?php
$req_dump = print_r($_SERVER, TRUE);
$fp = fopen('/tmp/request.log', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $req_dump);
fclose($fp);
echo "hello world";
```

However, the output looks like below:

```
Array
(
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => anaconda/13.21.195
    [HTTP_HOST] => 10.0.188.97
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [HTTP_X_ANACONDA_ARCHITECTURE] => x86_64
    [HTTP_X_ANACONDA_SYSTEM_RELEASE] => Red Hat Enterprise Linux
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_0] => eth0 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_1] => eth1 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_2] => eth2 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_3] => eth3 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4] => eth4 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_5] => eth5 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx
    [PATH] => /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 10.0.188.97 Port 80</address>

    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
    [SERVER_NAME] => 10.0.188.97
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 10.0.188.97
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 10.0.188.212
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/ks.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 59188
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /ks.php/images/install.img
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /ks.php
    [PATH_INFO] => /images/install.img
    [PATH_TRANSLATED] => /var/www/html/images/install.img
    [PHP_SELF] => /ks.php/images/install.img
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1402439673
)
```

How I tried to access the array:

FYI, here is the code how I tried to access that array:

```
# ks.php
<?php
$Table = array(
"00:02:C9:10:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.91",
"00:02:C9:4F:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.92",
"00:02:C9:53:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.93",
"00:02:C9:56:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.94",
"00:02:C9:53:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.95",
"00:02:C9:4E:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.96",
"00:02:C9:5A:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.97",
);

?>
...
%post
...
printf 'DEVICE=eth4 \nIPADDR=<?php echo $Table[$_SERVER["HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4"]]; ?>' > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth4 
service network restart
...
%end
```

The output doesn't look like straight forward to me. Say I want to get the MAC address of ethernet4, and `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4"]` doesn't work for me. 
Can anyone help me explain how to achieve that in PHP?

Comment: could you show your actual piece of code where you are attempting to get the value of `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4"] ` ?

Comment: @shatheesh Info added.

Comment: your `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4']` output is `eth4 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx` which also has a prefix `eth4 ` where as your `$Table` has `00:02:C9:4F:aa:bb` which makes the keys mismatch and actually you are trying to get `$Table['eth4 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx']` which is non existent in your `$Table` array

Comment: @JakeGould the point is  OP has added the log to track the output of `$_SERVER` and he is accessing the values directly from `$_SERVER`

Comment: @shatheesh nice observation sir. I got confused by the key name which I was assuming it is the Mac only. If you can post your answer, I will accept it. And thanks for the effort from other people too. :)

Comment: @B.Mr.W. posted my answer. If I am helpful do accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4']` output is `eth4 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx` which also has a prefix eth4 where as your `$Table` has `00:02:C9:4F:aa:bb` which makes the keys mismatch and actually you are trying to get `$Table['eth4 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx']` which is non existent in your `$Table` array

Try this:

```
// We are splitting the mac address by space so that $macAddress contains '00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx' and $eth contains eth4 

list($eth,$macAddress) = explode(' ',$_SERVER['HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4']);

// Make sure the value in $macAddress => 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx is 00:02:C9:4F:aa:bb or change your array accordingly


$Table = array(
"00:02:C9:10:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.91",
"00:02:C9:4F:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.92",
"00:02:C9:53:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.93",
"00:02:C9:56:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.94",
"00:02:C9:53:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.95",
"00:02:C9:4E:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.96",
"00:02:C9:5A:aa:bb" => "10.0.188.97",
);

$finalAddress = $Table[$macAddress]; 

printf 'DEVICE=eth4 \nIPADDR=<?php echo $finalAddress ; ?>' > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth4 '
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just save the array, it becomes like a useless print out.  To make it accessible, use `json_encode` when you save it:

```
$fp = fopen('/tmp/request.log', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($_SERVER));
fclose($fp);
```

Note how I removed the `print_r` since it’s unnecessary for a task like this. I also changed `fopen` to overwrite the file using `w` instead of `a` so the saved JSON is valid.

Then when you open the file, just use `json_decode` like this:

```
$server_variables_json = file_get_contents('/tmp/request.log');
$server_variables = json_decode($server_variables_json , true);
```

Then `$server_variables` is an actual array you can act on like this:

```
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4', $server_variables)) {
  echo $server_variables['HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4'];
}
```

The `if (array_key_exists(…))` is something I put in place to help me debug this locally on my machine since I don’t have `HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4` set in my `$_SERVER` values.

A simple check I did locally to debug this—since I don’t have `HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4` in my setup—was just to get the `HTTP_HOST` like this:

```
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_HOST', $server_variables)) {
  echo $server_variables['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of removing beautiful print, it helped me debug that there is a prefix eth4 in the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes to identify a non-numeric index:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4'];
```

You can get more [basic information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) from the docs themselves.

Edit: I am not sure what you mean:

```
<?php
    $array=array(
        'HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_0' => 'eth0 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx',
        'HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_1' => 'eth1 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx',
        'HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_2' => 'eth2 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx',
        'HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_3' => 'eth3 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx',
        'HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4' => 'eth4 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx',
        'HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_5' => 'eth5 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx'
    );
    echo "Printing just a single element.\r\n";
    echo $array['HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4'];

    echo "Printing the whole variable:\r\n";
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Outputs the following:

```
Printing just a single element.
eth4 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx
Printing the whole variable:
Array
(
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_0] => eth0 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_1] => eth1 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_2] => eth2 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_3] => eth3 B4:99:BA:07:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4] => eth4 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx
    [HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_5] => eth5 00:02:C9:4F:xx:xx
)
```

Comment: sorry Sir... typo, can you review my question?

Comment: @JakeGould No probs, I answered the question that was posted at the time - it seems that they are quite different now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the var $_SERVER["HTTP_X_RHN_PROVISIONING_MAC_4"], don't forgot the quotes.